# In CSS flexbox, how can I wrap a div so that it lays out like its child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When styling an element with flexbox I often have two different types of layout, one that fills its parent (flex:1) and divides up its space for children, and one that uses its child's space to calculate its own height (flex: unset).

It's also often nice to wrap a div in another div that is indistinguishable from its child, in order to add more functionality - this especially in the case of React in order to compose components.

How can I wrap div so that it expands to its parent if the child does, or remains at the child height otherwise.

Here is a JS bin for explanation - 
https://jsbin.com/muvihal/edit?html,css,output

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  flex: inherit;
  border: 5px dashed red;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.b {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
.b2 {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the dotted element 'a' to automatically take the same size as the blue elements b and b2 as in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVw4C.png

Comment: Am I missing something? The dotted items appear to take the same size as the blue elements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo sorry the bin wasn't the same as the code in the question, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Hopefully fixing the jsbin has made things clearer. I'm not sure how to explain things better - I want the 'a' class to behave like it's respective child. 'b' says it wants to fill its parent, so wrapping 'a' around it should also fill its parents. 'b2' wants to be 200px and so wrapping 'a' around it should also be 200px. Effectively the result is that having 'a' there or not should not affect the layout.

Comment: In the first example you want the `a` element to stretch to height of the outer container, in the second you don't. These two requirements require two different values for the flex shorthand property. How about just adding a utility class when you want to stretch? like so: https://jsbin.com/muvihal/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Danield your edit didn't appear to me in that link. The use case is in web frameworks where composing components is common, where it's not known what the child element will be. I do suspect what I'm asking for is impossible

Comment: @JakeCoxon https://jsbin.com/piripisebo/1/edit?html,css,output